# change the components of one panel when an event occurs in another people

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tabview

Suppose I have a left hand side panel and I want to change the forms in another panel based on the event of components on left panel.
How can I do it in JSF?

I searched a little bit and found that tabView in primefaces can do something like this.
But I would like to know whether there is another way of changing contents of another panel
from some event of one panel.

I understand that this question is not quite specific but I searched on google and couldn't find satisfactory answer so asking here.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Why did you tag primefaces, have you worked with it ?

Comment: RongNK yes sir, currently I am working with primemfaces for building an application. I have used components like tabView, panel, charts and datatable. Is it improper to tag primefaces in a question like this? sorry if I have done it. I will go through the rules for questions once again

Comment: "change the forms in another panel based on the event of components on left panel.". if you use Primefaces, i think it is simple.

Comment: RongNK sir but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Do I need to use backing beans the member variables represent the components on jsf page? Do I have to bind those components to UIInput and UIOutput in my managedBean?

Comment: On left panel, you can use html tag or jsf component(i think you want jsf component). "another panel" you can swap in `<ui:define`,`<ui:include`  with src get from bean, src will include facelets file, and when the component(from left panel) fire event, it will change the src.

Comment: If the `another panel` have some `panel`, you can use `render` attribute(bind to bean variable) to select the panel you want when component fire event.

Comment: RongNK yes I will surely look into this :) thank you for the help

Comment: Self-leaner, i will post answer in last night :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. You have some context in center:**

Left:

```
<p:commandButton update="pncenter" actionListener="#{bean.update}"/>
```

Center:

```
<p:outputPanel id="pncenter">
<p:outputPanel id="pn1" rendered="#{bean.render eq '1'}">
  // content here
</p:outputPanel>
<p:outputPanel id="pn2" rendered="#{bean.render eq '2'}">
  // content here
</p:outputPanel>
///....
</p:outputPanel>
```

**2. You have dynamic center:**(Each center context is stored in a xhtml file)

Left:

```
<p:commandButton update="pncenter" actionListener="#{bean.update}"/>
```

Center:

```
<p:outputPanel id="pncenter">
  <ui:include src="#{centerBean.link}"/>
</p:outputPanel>
```

bean.update method

```
centerBean.link = "/module/test1.xhtml"; // /module/test2.xhtml  /module/test3.xhtml
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This helped a lot. I still have one doubt
If I use a p:layoutUnit instead of p:panel then the layoutUnit is not updated and the changes are reflected only after I refresh the page.
I had to put another panel in layoutUnit to make it work.
What can be the issue there?

Comment: I'm using <pe:layoutPane (Primefaces extendsion), it work fine. You are using p:layoutUnit and it have some issues ?